# Extending FOSUserBundles Registration to have different fields stored in different tables?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle, extending

I am new with Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle. I am using Symfony2 version 2.4.1. I would like to extend FOSUserBundle in a few ways. I want to add fields to the registration form, some fields i would like to add to the user table which contains username and password but i would like to add fields that get added to a different table. (I think i have to rewrite the registerController??)

Currently i have inherited FOSUserBundle into my own UserBundle. I have tried to simply add fields to the current registration form by following the documentation but i keep returning this error.

**Could not load type "acme_user_registration"**

// src/Fixie/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

```
    <?php

namespace Fixie\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max="255",
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $name;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

I then add the name field to the form builder

// src/Fixie/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php

```
 <?php

namespace Fixie\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_user_registration';
    }
}
```

I then go on to declare the custom form type:

// src/Fixie/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
    acme_user.registration.form.type:
        class: Fixie\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: acme_user_registration }
```

Then updated config:

```
 fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Fixie\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
           type: acme_user_registration
```

//AppKernel.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new Fixie\WelcomeBundle\WelcomeBundle(),
            new Fixie\UserBundle\UserBundle(),

            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

// Fixie/UserBundle/UserBundle.php

```
<?php

namespace Fixie\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

My main questions are:

1. Can anyone see an error with my current code?
2. In relation to extending the form to have multiple fields being stored in multiple tables. What are the step i have to take? Do i rewrite the logic of the controller and the form???

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do in console `app/console container:debug`. Can you see in output your form service `acme_user.registration.form.type` ?

Comment: No I cant see it. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Can you post your AppKernel.php ?

Comment: added it there @denys281

Comment: Are you loading the `services.yml` file in your DI? The entity/model won't be a problem as they're not loaded at the point the form is requested and the bundle does not need to have 'FOSUserBundle' as a parent to be able to rewrite the form, this is only really necessary for things like controllers, templates and routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

In appKerenl.php you have

```
 new Fixie\UserBundle\UserBundle(),
```

But in `service.yml`

```
class: Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
```

Maybe it should be:

```
class: Fixie\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
```

If in result of command `app/console container:debug` you can't see `acme_user.registration.form.type`  it means that your service don't register and  `fos_user` can't see you service, and can't find your form type.

My UserBundle store in `Webmil/Joint/UserBundle`. In `UserBundle` folder I have file `WebmilJointUserBundle.php`

My file:

```
<?php

namespace Webmil\Joint\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class WebmilJointUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

So I think that your problem in this file. Can you compare file and your file, and maybe you will find error.

Comment: I changed that to Fixie\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType but i still cant see acme_user.registration.form.type when i run app/console container:debug. I have amended the above code to reflect this.

Comment: So if I put the services part in my app/config.yml i can see it when i go app/console container:debug so it is only not registering the service when it is in the bundle.

Comment: @bowseph First I think we need, that your service load from your UserBundle.I think I know where your problem and why even from app/config your service doesn't work. Can you post contents of file `Fixie/UserBundle/FixieUserBundle.php` ?

Comment: I have added the equivalent file from my project and cannot see any difference. I have tried making a new Bundle just to test out if I could register a bundle from there and i was able to. Should i just create a new bundle and move all my files into it and see if it will register then? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Try rename file from `UserBundle.php` to `FixieUserBundle.php`. And yes you can create new bundle. I hade same problem,  and spent nearly 1 hour to find this problem))

Comment: Finally have the service registered! The problem was solved by regenerating the bundle! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

With me it was that i had already a services.yml in app/config, so the one in my bundle was ignored. In the end I added the registry to this file

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:

    # [other already existing services]

    acme_user.registration.form.type:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: acme_user_registration }
```